# How to run specific program with root privileges (Ubuntu OS) when no sudo user log into system?

Tags: ubuntu, security, login, boot, privileges

How do I run a specific program with root privileges (Ubuntu OS) when no sudo user is logged into the system? The program needs root privileges to function correctly. A normal user shouldn't be able to shutdown this process. 
For example, I have two users, Admin and Client;
The program should start only when the client logs into the system. It needs root privileges and the Client shouldn't be able to shut this process down.

Answer (score 7):

There are a few ways to do this.  Ubuntu's graphical login is provided by GDM (or KDM if you're using Kubuntu).  GDM is started by the Upstart subsystem.

**The startup process follows these steps:**

1. System boots.  Upstart starts services, including GDM (*/etc/init/gdm*).
2. GDM starts, initializes the X-server (*/etc/gdm/Init/**), and presents the GUI login window.
3. A user logs in.

   1. PAM authorization happens (*/etc/pam.d/gdm*)
   2. GDM runs ***PostLogin*** script (*/etc/gdm/PostLogin/**).
   3. GDM runs ***PreSession*** script (*/etc/gdm/PreSession/**).
   4. GDM runs ***Xsession*** and ***xinit*** scripts
      (*/etc/gdm/Xsession*, */etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc.d/**, */etc/X11/Xsession*, */etc/X11/Xsession.d/**)
4. The user's desktop appears.

---

**Where to run your script**

Everything prior to ***XSession*** runs as root.  */etc/gdm/Xsession* and everything after runs as the user.  This leaves you with three real options for *where* to run your script.

1. Modify GDM/KDM's ***PostLogin*** or ***PreSession*** scripts to run your program.  The username is available in the *USER* or *USERNAME* environment variables.
2. Use PAM to execute your script.  PAM will set the authorizing user in the *PAM_USER* environment variable.  Add this to */etc/pam.d/gdm* to kick off your script:

   ```
   auth  required  pam_exec.so   /path/to/your/script
   ```

   - You might be able to use PAM to match a particular user ([as in this answer](https://superuser.com/questions/119254/how-to-switch-users-without-entering-password/119813#119813)), so the script would only run for that user and wouldn't need to match users itself.  I don't have the PAM expertise to explain how to do that.
3. [Write an Upstart script](https://superuser.com/questions/133595/running-a-script-on-startup-before-x-starts-in-ubuntu-9-10/133625#133625) to run your program.  Your script would start at user login, so we look for the ***desktop-session-start*** signal emitted by GDM's ***PreSession*** script.

   So an Upstart script would detect that signal as the run trigger:

   ```
   # start when GDM's PreSession script runs
   start on desktop-session-start
   ```

   The signal from ***PreSession*** doesn't pass along the username, so you'd need to tweak the signal.  In */etc/gdm/PreSession/Default*, find the *initctl* line and change it to this.  You could also use *USERNAME* in place of *USER*.

   ```
   # add USER variable so Upstart script can find it
   initctl -q emit desktop-session-start DISPLAY_MANAGER=gdm USER=$USER
   ```

   See the manpages for [Upstart](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/karmic/en/man5/init.5.html) and its [*starting* event](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/karmic/en/man7/starting.7.html) for more details.

---

**How to avoid the Admin user**

Your script will need to examine the user/username in the environment variables it gets from one of these methods and use that to determine whether to abort or continue.  Standard shell-scripting methods will work.  Depending on which starting location you chose from the above list, the username may be available in the *USER*, *USERNAME*, or *PAM_USER* environment variables.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [setuid](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jaunty/man1/setuid.1.html), to always run the program as root. From a security point of view, this is probably a very, very bad idea. If one of your users managed to exploit the setuid program it will give them root access to the whole server

Comment: that works if it's a program the user *wants* to run.  i don't think that's what this questioner is looking for tho.