# How to remove unwanted entries in the grub boot loader

Tags: ubuntu-10.04, grub

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>    [Aesthetically editing grub.cfg](https://superuser.com/questions/111302/aesthetically-editing-grub-cfg)

How do I remove unwanted entries in the GRUB boot loader?
There is still an entry for Windows Vista even when it doesn't exist anymore. And the Memtest entry its also unneeded. How do I remove those entries from the GRUB boot loader that came with ubuntu 10.04?

**EDIT**

I opened the grub.cfg file. What do I need to remove in here. So that the entry for Windows 7 and ubuntu 10.04 and ubuntu 10.04 safe mode is left.
I'm afraid I would ruin something if I just deleted what I think should be deleted so I consult it here first.

Comment: your question is probably answered in http://superuser.com/questions/102692/make-grub-keep-its-default-boot-under-kernel-updates or in http://superuser.com/questions/111302/aesthetically-editing-grub-cfg or in http://superuser.com/questions/137875/can-grub-be-configured-to-remember-the-last-os-you-booted-into -- please read them first, and edit your question to note what you don't understand, so answers here can specify.  without further information this will likely be closed as a duplicate of one of those or another question.

Comment: clearly you haven't read the answers given in the other posts...  if you had you wouldn't be trying to edit */boot/grub/grub.cfg* ...